# Structured Prolog code not running

Tags: prolog

I am trying to run following structured code from http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/prolog-find-factorial-given-number-3072.aspx in SWI-Prolog:

```
predicates
    start
    find_factorial(real,real)

goal
    clearwindow,
    start.

clauses
    start:-
        write("Enter non negative number = "),
        readreal(Num),
        Result = 1.0,
        find_factorial(Num,Result).

    find_factorial(Num,Result):-
        Num <> 0,
        NewResult = Num * Result,
        NewNum = Num - 1,
        find_factorial(NewNum,NewResult).

    find_factorial(_,Result):-
        write("Factorial = ",Result),nl.
```

But there are 3 "Syntax error: Operator expected" at startup and it does not run:

```
?- start.
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: start/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Where is the problem and how can I run such code?

Comment: This so-called "structured code" is written using Visual (or Turbo or PDC) Prolog specific language constructs. It won't run as-is in SWI or GNU Prolog.

Comment: I get it. I was not aware of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To port your code to Prolog, remove the `predicates` section, convert the `goal` section into a standard `initialization/1` directive:

```
:- initialization(start).
```

Remove also the `clauses` section header. You will also need to port some of the calls in the clause bodies (not tested):

```
start:-
    write('Enter non negative number = '),
    read(Num),
    Result = 1.0,
    find_factorial(Num,Result).

find_factorial(Num,Result):-
    Num > 0,
    NewResult = Num * Result,
    NewNum = Num - 1,
    find_factorial(NewNum,NewResult).

find_factorial(_,Result):-
    write('Factorial = '), write(Result), nl.
```

But note that this code is seriously flawed. E.g. it mixes computation (of factorial) with output of the calculated value. I leave those fixes to you.